# Why is Capacitor Storage not storing or retrieving any information from Storage with Ionic React?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I am trying to implement Capacitor Storage with Ionic React, but in the web it works properly, while when I build the application in Android it is not working, i.e. it does not read or save anything from/in local Storage, does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Hi! Can you show me the code of how you implemented the Storage into a Page? I cant get it running with Ionic React and Capacitor in Pages. I just receive Promise all the time. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, we decided to use SQLite since we did not manage to make it work with Storage API.

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try!

Comment: I would have a guess it was because Storage works on strings only. On web it works (somehow) with non-string values but on emulator or real device you need to stringify/parse data to store/read non-string values.
More detail: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/storage